# method interrupted in java,when use it inside while loop will interrupt the thread or not?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I use this method like this, will it interrupt the thread or not?

```
while ( !interrupted() && more work to do){ /* main thread execution loop*/ }
```

2nd question: what does this statement mean?

> interrupt() method, does not automatically mean that the thread should
>   terminate.  It simply grabs the attention of the thread (kind of like
>   poking a sleeping roommate to wake him up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `interrupted()` does not “interrupt” execution of code in the Thread.  Your condition will, however, cause the loop to exit if the Thread running it is interrupted by another thread calling [interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) on it, assuming no other code in the loop calls `interrupted()` (which clears the current Thread’s interrupted status).

The text you have quoted is explaining that a Thread’s code must *act* on an interrupt, by checking the Thread’s interrupted status, or by calling a method capable of throwing InterruptedException (or [ClosedByInterruptException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html)).  If the Thread’s code does none of those things, calling `interrupt()` on that Thread will have no effect on code execution;  it will merely set the Thread’s interrupted status, which is just a boolean property of the Thread.  Code must properly respond to interrupts for interrupts to be effective.